# Galois group of the polynomial coming from an irreducible representation.

Tags: representation-theory, galois-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $(V, \sigma)$ be a non-trivial irreducible (complex) representation of $G$. Let $\chi$ denotes the corresponding character and define the polynomial $p(x)=\prod_{g\in G}(x-\chi(g))$ over $\mathbf C$.

Is there anything known about this polynomial? In particular, what can we say about its Galois group? **EDIT:** It is not even clear to me whether this polynomial always is a rational polynomial (I was tacitly assuming this before). But because of the symmetry it seems that it should be.

All I can see is that the coefficient of $x^{|G|-1}$ is $0$ since it is equal to $|G|$ times the inner product of $\chi$ with the character coming from the trivial representation.

Comment: Do you think that this polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: That's my gut feeling.

Comment: But this gut feeling is wrong. An exercise in Fulton (which I have not solved) says that the character corresponding to an irreducible representation of dimension greater that 1 vanishes at some conjugacy class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer. Yes, the constant term of this polynomial is $0$ if $\chi$ is non-linear: a theorem of Burnside states that every non-linear complex character has a zero. For a linear character $\lambda$, one can prove the constant term is $\pm 1$. So you could think one should focus on linear characters. Still then, take a linear integral character, for example the non-principal linear of $S_4$, then $p(x)=(x-1)(x+1)^6(x-1)^3(x-1)^8(x+1)^6=(x^2-1)^{12}$.

Comment: Thanks. My thinking was cloudy before, as I realize now, but do you think this polynomial is necessarily a rational polynomial?

Comment: Yes, let $n=|G|$, and let $E$ be a splitting field for $x^n-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})$ acts on (and fixes the symmetrical expressions) of the the values of the characters, hence they are rational integers.

Comment: Thanks. That's great.

Comment: I am having some trouble executing your argument to prove rationality of the polynomial. Suppose I just want to show that $a_1=\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)$ is rational. Let $n=\dim V$ and let $\lambda_{1, g}, \ldots, \lambda_{n, g}$ be all the eigenvalues of $\sigma_g$. Then each $\lambda_{i, g}$ is an $n$-th root of unity. Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity and define $E$ as the splitting field of $x^n-1$ over $\mathbb Q$. Then $E=\mathbb Q(\zeta)$. Pick $\tau\in \text{Gal}(E:\mathbb Q)$. Then $\tau(\zeta)=\zeta^k$ for some $k$ relatively prime with $n$. (continued)

Comment: Now $\tau(a_1)= \sum_{g\in G} \tau(\chi(g)) = \sum_{g\in G}\tau(\lambda_{1, g}+\cdots + \lambda_{n, g})$. This gives $\tau(a_1) = \sum_{g\in G}(\lambda_{1, g}^k+\cdots +\lambda_{n, g}^k) = \sum_{g\in G}\chi(g^k)$. So we must show that $\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g) = \sum_{g\in G}\chi(g^k)$ whenever $\gcd(k, n)=1$. I am stuck here.

Comment: Oh. The map $G\to G$ taking $x$ to $x^k$ is bijective. This is because if $x^k=y^k$, then choosing $l$ such that $kl\equiv 1\pmod{n}$, we have that $x^{kl}=y^{kl}$, giving $x=y$. Surprisingly, I didn't know this simple fact before. Did you have the same proof in mind?

Comment: Yes this is exactly the proof, it is quite classical in character theory. Great you discovered this yourself!!